# Grouping by a SUM range of values SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table of UserIDs and payment amounts. I want to SUM all of the UserID's payments and then group them into ranges. The ranges are 'Small' (total of between £1 - £499), 'Medium' (£500 - £4,999) and 'Large' ( £5,000 +)

So if UserID has made 4 different payments of £100 then he will appear as UserID: 76867 Range Amount 'Small'

My current query gives me each UserID and which range their total fall into

```
SELECT 
 SERIALNUMBER ,  Case when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 1 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 500 then 'small' when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 499 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 5000 then 'medium' when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 5000 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 10000000 then 'large' END  AS 'Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT'  
FROM BATCHDETAIL
WHERE  (DATEOFPAYMENT > '2017/07/31') AND (DATEOFPAYMENT < '2018/08/01')  
GROUP BY SERIALNUMBER
```

But what I need to now is to summarise how many userIDs belong in each range

```
Range  |  Count of UserIDs  
-------|----------------  
Small  |       23  
-------|----------------  
Medium |       08
```

(apologies for bad formatting). Any help/questions would be greatly appreciated as always!!
Thanks
Lee

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your select statement into a subquery. I assumed that Serialnumber is a UserID and that you want to count distinct users in each group.

```
     Select [Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT] as 'Range', 
count(distinct Serialnumber) as  'Count of UserIDs' FROM
            (
            SELECT  
             SERIALNUMBER ,  
        Case when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 1 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 500 then 'small' 
        when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 499 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 5000 then 'medium' 
        when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 5000 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 10000000 then 'large' END  AS 'Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT'  
            FROM BATCHDETAIL
            WHERE  (DATEOFPAYMENT > '2017/07/31') AND (DATEOFPAYMENT < '2018/08/01')  
        GROUP BY SERIALNUMBER
        ) s
 group by [Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT]
```

Comment: Thanks, this also gave me exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a CTE (Common Table Expression) with your original select, so you can now easily group its result to count the appearances of every range.

```
with Ranges as
(
  SELECT SERIALNUMBER ,  Case when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 1 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 500 then 'small' when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 499 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 5000 then 'medium' when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 5000 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 10000000 then 'large' END  AS 'Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT'  
  FROM BATCHDETAIL
  WHERE  (DATEOFPAYMENT > '2017/07/31') AND (DATEOFPAYMENT < '2018/08/01')  
  GROUP BY SERIALNUMBER
)

select 'Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT', count(*) as 'Count of UserIDs'
from Ranges
group by 'Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT'
```

Comment: I was getting an error message of: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use your query as sub-query and group by it again on 'Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT'

```
select [Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT] , count(SERIALNUMBER) 
from (
SELECT 
SERIALNUMBER ,  Case when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 1 and    SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 500 then 'small' 
when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 499 and SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT)    < 5000 then 'medium' 
when SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) > 5000 and    SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) < 10000000 then 'large' END  AS [Sum of    PAYMENTAMOUNT]
   FROM BATCHDETAIL
   WHERE  (DATEOFPAYMENT > '2017/07/31') AND (DATEOFPAYMENT < '2018/08/01')  
 GROUP BY SERIALNUMBER
  ) as t1
group by [Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT]
```

Comment: Amazing! That did exactly what I wanted. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to do it in two levels (using subquery):

```
select
    count(*) as cnt
,   Case 
        when a.total_payment >= 10000000 then 'large+'
        when a.total_payment >= 5000 then 'large' 
        when a.total_payment >= 500 then 'medium' 
        when a.total_payment >= 1 then 'small' 
        else 'too small'
        end AS "Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT"

from (
    SELECT 
        SERIALNUMBER
    ,   SUM(BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTAMOUNT) as total_payment
    FROM BATCHDETAIL
    WHERE  (DATEOFPAYMENT > '2017/07/31') AND (DATEOFPAYMENT < '2018/08/01')  
    GROUP BY SERIALNUMBER
) as a
group by "Sum of PAYMENTAMOUNT"
```

BTW, you missed some of the ranges.

Comment: Thanks for answering this so quickly. I got an error message of Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference and it didn't like 'a.PAYMENTAMOUNT' as a column name either.

Comment: That is because I copied it from original code snippet. For column names in sql you should use not single, but double quotes. Sorry for not fixing right away.

Comment: a-ha I didn't know that! That is very useful to know!